# Migration from MySQL to Neo4j

Tags: php, neo4j

I am trying to build a PHP application for migrating data from MySQL to Neo4j.

1. What are the best possible ways to approach towards the above mentioned goal?
2. Is there any way to acess Neo4j shell by PHP? Suppose I want to execute this command as mentioned by [Bruggen](http://blog.bruggen.com/2013/10/importing-my-lastfm-dataset-neo4j-way.html) in this blog to import csv files into neo4j, can I execute it in my PHP code?

Comment: Can you send me your sql scheme? How you will store it in neo4j? TIA.

Comment: use batch inserting if you use server version

Answer (score 0):

Use the Neo4jPHP driver from Josh Adell, there are also sample projects listet on

http://neo4j.org/develop/php

I think there are no built-in ways to access the shell from Neo4jPHP but if you can use its http facilities, you can do something [like I did here](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/02/on-using-neo4j-shell-with-basic-auth-over-http-on-a-remote-server/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply Michael. First I was looking for some approaches for migrating data from mysql to neo4j from your experience, can you please suggest any? Second I have read the mentioned blog of yours but my requirement is on local rather then remote. Can you tell me how can I use its http feature in this case?

Comment: You create a graph model on a whiteboard, then connect to your relational database and read the data from there and write it to the graph model, you can also create an intermediary csv file that you then import into the graph.